# Using grep command within .zshrc : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, zsh

I have a function inside .zshrc ( shell is zsh).

```
test1(){
     toprint=$(ps -ef | grep $1)
     echo $toprint
}
```

Which gives following output.

```
 asiri  ~  test1 gradle
 grep: gradle: No such file or directory
```

After some research I have found out that there is an alias added by syntax highlighting plugin

```
zsh -x 2>zsh.trace
exit
grep 'alias.*grep' zsh.trace
#part of output
+/home/asiri/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh:593> eval $'.... long string here..
+(eval):132> alias 'grep=grep --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn,.idea,.tox}'
```

Since its added as a part of a script I'm unable to comment it out.
But where there is no such alias set ( one of my other linux vm) above function works fine.
Please let know if there is a way to resolve this issue.
I tried 'unalias' also, adding it in .zshrc file. It also didn't fix the problem.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use `ps -ef | \grep "$1"` or `ps -ef | command grep "$1"` or even better use `pgrep`

Comment: Non of above works :-(

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the function and alias you provided. Can you please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question?

Comment: I can reproduce this in my environment. I'm not 100% sure this happens because of the alias. May be there is another cause which i'm not aware about. But this happens in my several vms where even zsh is not installed. Cannot find either the proper cause or a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path of grep:
`/usr/bin/grep`

Comment: I updated the question. It also doesnt work